# Window bounds set on window using AppleScript in OS X are being ignored

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to create a small AppleScript to create and move some Terminal windows around my screen. The problem I am running into is that in some cases, it seems that OS X is ignoring the bounds I am setting.

Using the AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Terminal" to set the bounds of the first window to {0, 50, 600, 700}
tell application "Terminal" to get the bounds of the first window
```

Shows the following in the Event Log:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set bounds of window 1 to {0, 50, 600, 700}
    get bounds of window 1
        --> {0, 22, 600, 672}
end tell
Result:
{0, 22, 600, 672}
```

Visually inspecting the window that is created when the script runs shows that Result bounds are the ones being used by the window.

Any ideas?

Edit: Running 10.6.3. My screen size is 1280 X 800. Finder reports the bounds of the desktop window to be {0, 0, 1280, 800}

Comment: can I ask why you are doing this ? If you just want to tile your terminals there is already a script for that you can get for free

Comment: That is basically what I am doing...however, I also add some additional customization like open a couple tabs and launching commands in each tab. And now that I see this behavior I am trying to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hit the same problem today. Not sure what the real cause is, but the workaround is to add an extra "set position" after set bounds:

```
# from my window tiling script:
set the bounds of the first window to {0, 22, (screenWidth / 2), screenHeight}
set position of the first window to {0, 22}
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes when telling an application to set the bounds doesn't work, telling System Events to change the position and size properties does:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Live"
    set position of window 1 to {0, 50}
    set size of window 1 to {600, 650}
end tell
```

Comment: This helped me with Terminal, which was misbehaving for the normal bounds setting. It also works reliably across all other apps I've tested so far.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here. since update to mavericks I can't set width of window larger than default. Above workaround does not work but setting position and size separately via works:

set position of ... to {...,..} and then
set size of .. to {..,..}

works